# Split series and replace with `\t` in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split, dataframe

My data type is `pandas.core.series.Series`. There are two columns. I want to split one of them from

```
V1      V2
1000    1 2 3 
1001    0 2
```

to

```
1000 \t 1 \t 2 \t 3
1001 \t 0 \t 2
```

What I tried:

```
1.
list(result.columns.values)
result[list(result.columns.values)].str.split('  ').replace('/t')

2.
result['labels'].split('  ', expand=True)

3.
c = str(result['labels'])
c.split(' ')
```

I have tried other methods, like use `awk` or regular expression. Unfortunately, I cannot believe I did not find a answer on the doc or stackoverflow.

NOTE: the number of variables increases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concanecate both columns together with casting to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) if type of column `V1` is `int` and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) or [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
print df
     V1     V2
0  1000  1 2 3
1  1001    0 2

s = df['V1'].astype(str) + ' '  + df['V2'] 
print s.replace('\s+', r'\t')
0    1000 1 2 3
1      1001 0 2
dtype: object

print s.str.replace('\s+', r'\t')
0    1000\t1\t2\t3
1       1001\t0\t2
dtype: object
```

Or maybe you need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) `'\t'`:

```
print df
         V2
V1         
1000  1 2 3
1001    0 2

df1 = df['V2'].str.split('\s+', expand=True)
print df1
      0  1     2
V1              
1000  1  2     3
1001  0  2  None

df1 = df1.fillna('').reset_index()
df1['V1'] = df1['V1'].astype(str)

df1 = df1.T.apply('\t'.join)
df1 = df1.str.strip('\t')
print df1
0    1000\t1\t2\t3
1       1001\t0\t2
dtype: object
```

Comment: But replace `\t` is unclear, maybe can you explain better?  New columns? Joining like my answer?

Comment: Great! One more question: If I will do such task intensively, do I need to learn regular expression?

Comment: Hmmm, it depends of your data... Maybe.